# Python Unresolved import error with IBPY

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pydev, ibpy

I am new to Python, and I am using PyDev in Eclipse to practice Python, the interpreter is Python 3.5.

I am trying to develop Python code to access Interactive Brokers, simply copying the code described in the link:

https://www.quantstart.com/articles/using-python-ibpy-and-the-interactive-brokers-api-to-automate-trades

I downloaded the latest IBPY library (ib-0.8.0), and installed it using command

> python setup.py install

However, I got errors at the very beginning after I copied the code

```
   from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
   from ib.ext.Order import Order
   from ib.opt import Connection, message
```

PyDev show unresolved import for ***Contract***, ***Order***, and ***Connection***, ***message***

I checked the extracted library folder for IBPY, they are all there

Can someone help me findout what is the reason?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved, the IBPY source code contains errors

```
python setup.py install
```

report code syntax errors, after I correct the errors, the unresolved import problem disappear, it seems the source was corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem by running:

```
pip3 install ibapi
```

Comment: ibpy and ibapi are 2 different packages.  The ibapi package from pip is not the official source for ibapi.  Read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57618526/2855515