# Error encountered with Interactive Brokers API - Market data farm connection issues, API version error, and unsuccessful update attempt

Tags: python, python-3.x, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I'm encountering an issue with my Python script utilizing the Interactive Brokers API. The script is aimed at retrieving market data, but I'm encountering several errors. Here's a summary of the problem and the code snippet:

Error Summary:

> ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
> ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cafarm
> ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
> ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
> ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
> ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefil
> ERROR 1 10285 Your API version does not support fractional size rules. Please upgrade to a minimum version 163.

Additional Information:
I attempted to update the Interactive Brokers API using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade ibapi
```

However, this update did not resolve the issue.
Code Snippet:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)

def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

# Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1)  # Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

# Create contract object
eurusd_contract = Contract()
eurusd_contract.symbol = 'EUR'
eurusd_contract.secType = 'CASH'
eurusd_contract.exchange = 'IDEALPRO'
eurusd_contract.currency = 'USD'

# Request Market Data
app.reqMktData(1, eurusd_contract, '', False, False, [])

time.sleep(10)  # Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()
```

I'd appreciate any insights on why I'm encountering these errors and how to resolve them.

Comment: my main error is: "ERROR 1 10285 Your API version does not support fractional size rules. Please upgrade to a minimum version 163.". I don't care about "ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cafarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
ERROR -1 2104 Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
ERROR -1 2106 HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds
ERROR -1 2158 Sec-def data farm connection is OK:secdefil"

Comment: Don't install it using `pip3`/`pip`. The version there is not maintained. Install it according to the IBKR instructions.

Comment: There is an answer here on how to install the latest ibapi version:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618117/installing-the-ibapi-package

Comment: I went to your link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618117/installing-the-ibapi-package" but still see version "Version: 9.81.1.post1
" and not 10.19.2 as I just updated. I did:
"1) Download "API Latest" from http://interactivebrokers.github.io/

2) Unzip or install (if its a .msi file) the download.

3) Go to tws-api/source/pythonclient/

4) Build a wheel with: python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

5) Install the wheel with:

python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade dist/ibapi-10.19.2-py3-none-any.whl" @scima96

Comment: make sure you install the wheel in your project directory, not just the terminal.

Comment: I updated now, everything works now @scima96

Comment: Official IB TWS API does not support pip installation method. And currently, IB API has not supported fractional share trading yet. Please do not pip install ibapi. You have to go to https://interactivebrokers.github.io/# to set it up.